# Pick an image / video using PhoneGap in Android

Tags: android, cordova

How can I pick an image / video ( or take a photo / video ) using PhoneGap in Android ?

I have a web form needs to pick image / video contents and submit the form to upload the contents. Is PhoneGap capable to do so? or I have to fall back to native Android codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can upload image to server with phonegap

Here is the code to pick image or video

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}

    function capturePhoto() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI });
}

function getPhoto(source) {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source });
}

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    // do whatever with imageURI
}
```

in html you have to write

```
<button class="btn large" onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button>
<button class="btn large" onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From
        Photo Library</button>
```

for video

```
Camera.MediaType = { 
    PICTURE: 0,             // allow selection of still pictures only. DEFAULT. Will return format specified via DestinationType
    VIDEO: 1,               // allow selection of video only, WILL ALWAYS RETURN FILE_URI
    ALLMEDIA : 2     }
```

even you can go through this

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

Comment: but who to use COmeara.MediaType with sourceType  ?