# Impossible to pick video from gallery/library - phonegap/cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone, cordova-plugins

I am using windows phone, cordova/phonegap.
How is possible to pick a video from gallery as it was a picture?

The official plugin seems to work for picture only.

Here is the code:

```
function getVideo() {
    var options = { quality: 80 };
    options["sourceType"] = 0 | 2; 
    options["mediaType"] = 1;
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onVideoSuccess, onFail, options);    
}


var onVideoSuccess = function (fileuri) {
    console.log("fileuri " + fileuri);
}


var onFail = function (err) {
    console.log("onFail");
}
```

This way I can select the pictures only, shall I change any parameter to select the video files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some time to find it, but it is indeed possible by setting the MediaType.

```
var pictureSource; 
var destinationType; 
var mediaType;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    mediaType = navigator.camera.MediaType;
}

navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    mediaType: mediaType.VIDEO,
    sourceType: source
});

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
    console.log(imageURI);
}

function onFail(message) {
    console.log(message);
}
```

Found it in this answer: [Pick an image / video using PhoneGap in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116063/pick-an-image-video-using-phonegap-in-android)
More info: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

FYI:

```
Camera.MediaType = { 
    PICTURE: 0,             // allow selection of still pictures only. DEFAULT. Will return format specified via DestinationType
    VIDEO: 1,               // allow selection of video only, WILL ALWAYS RETURN FILE_URI
    ALLMEDIA : 2            // allow selection from all media types
```

So in your code, you should change

```
options["sourceType"] = 0 | 2;
```

to:

```
options["sourceType"] = 1;
```

to select only videos, or to:

```
options["sourceType"] = 0;
```

to select only pictures, or to:

```
options["sourceType"] = 2;
```

to select both.

Comment: right now I dont have time for verifying it, have you personally checked it?

Comment: Yes, it does work. There was a small error in your configuration, however. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This works in Cordova 5.4.1

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 100,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.VIDEO
  });
```

Related docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera#module_Camera.DestinationType

**UPDATE** - I take this back, it works for selecting videos in the UI, but I cannot get the `FILE_URI` in the `onSuccess` handler to get anything but an empty string, so I can't do anything after they select a video.

Comment: It's been a few years since I've been into the context of this situation, so I can't be certain. I seem to recall that I had to go with the "unofficial" camera plugin which had a fix for this problem when the "official" camera plugin had a long standing issue.

Comment: I found the camera plugin does work, but `<input type='file' />` does not. I was using `fileEntry.moveTo()`, which was removing the file, even though it was still visible on my phone. It looks like `fileEntry.moveTo()` on certain files doesn't completely remove them, showing they are still there while they're not. I ended up using `fileEntry.copyTo()` instead, so corrupted files don't attempt to go into my system. The corrupted files was my issue.

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein can I ask what the 'unofficial' plugin you used was? We don't even see the video thumbnails in the gallery to select

Comment: @user3919920 - maybe this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-camera-unofficial